# I have listed the pivotfields and pivot items under each of them using VBA. Why are some of my pivotfields showing no pivotitems?

Tags: excel, vba

I am rather new to VBA. I have a pivot table that has 6 filters. I was trying to change the filter value in one of the filters. As part of debugging, I listed all the fields and their pivot items. I then see that some of the pivot fields do not show any pivot items under them.
I tried allowing multiple select, making the pivotitems visible but to no vail. Can anybody guide me on how to add pivotitems under pivotfields? Thank you.

The code I used to list the items is as follows

I got it from microsoft documentation example. This was the code

```
Worksheets("sheet4").Activate 
With Worksheets("sheet3").PivotTables(1) 
c = 1 
For i = 1 To .PivotFields.Count 
   r = 1 
   Cells(r, c) = .PivotFields(i).Name 
   r = r + 1 
    For x = 1 To .PivotFields(i).PivotItems.Count 
      Cells(r, c) = .PivotFields(i).PivotItems(x).Name 
      r = r + 1 
    Next 
    c = c + 1 
 Next 
End With
```

I have checked the filters very thoroughly and there are items that I can select under the filters in the MS Excel sheet.

Comment: Pivotitems are there if they are (or were, depending on the retention settings) in your data. I suspect your code to list them may have been wrong.

Comment: @Rory thank you for taking a look. The code was nothing fancy. Let me put it on the original post. I cant format it here.

Comment: Is that the entire code, or is there an `On Error` statement somewhere in the actual code?

Comment: @Rory that is the entire code. When I run it, I get the fields as column headers and the pivot items below it. but for some fields i did not get any items though they show up when I click the drop don in the pivottable.

Comment: I can't replicate the issue. Can you post a workbook somewhere for me to have a look at?

Comment: @Rory It is on a secured network. Give me a couple of days to work on it. If I find a solution or cause, I will post it here.